# Make a character appear only once on VB6

Tags: vb6

I'm creating a simple calculator on VB6.

Here's my code I'm working on:

```
    textScreen.Text = textScreen.Text & "+"
```

Here's the result when I press some *number buttons*, followed by clicking on
the **plus sign button** several times:

```
    75+++++++
```

I would like the **plus sign** to appear only once, even if I click on
its button many times:

```
    92+
```

...and when I click on some *number buttons* again, followed by clicking
on the **plus sign button**, I would like the **plus sign** to show up again:

```
    58+4+
```

This is somehow similar to the default Calculator on Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there are different approaches for this. But in general, I wouldn't just concatenate some string. This way you'll have to parse the string later on, instead of just solving the requested term. Instead try to create some stack with your operations/numbers on it; just look on the web for calculator examples.

---

Anyway, for this, you'll have to somehow store the last operation (e.g. did I input a digit or an operator?)

If you'd like to limit the calculator to simple operations without brackets etc. you can use a boolean value for this:

```
Dim lastOp As Boolean
```

Then, before adding the `+` (or any other operator):

```
If Not lastOp Then
    textScreen.Text = textScreen.Text & "+"
    lastOp = true
End If
```

When adding any digit (e.g.):

```
lastOp = false
textScreen.Text = textScreen.Text & "0"
```

(Don't count on 100% error free code, I think I haven't touched VB6 for like 8 years.)

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. You're my hero! Thank you so much! +1 for you, too.

Answer (score 1):

You mighty just check if the last character in the text was "+" :

```
    If Mid(textScreen.Text, Len(textScreen.Text), 1) <> "+" Then
    textScreen.Text = textScreen.Text & "+"
    End If
```